# My password curl is failing sometimes?

Tags: php, curl

```
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $PathUrl);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'someuser:somepass');
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    $info = curl_getinfo($ch);
```

Any ideas on why it works about 30% of the time and the other 70% if fails....viewing the url on any browser works all the time

Comment: Fails how? Giving what error?

Comment: No there is no error but just an empty set somethings...and sometimes it returns the proper xml

Comment: might need to set the cookie? Or does the site require a CERT? Had an issue a while back where we needed a cert as the site went to HTTPS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may be better off setting the `Authorization` header via `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER`.

Eg, `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Authorization' => 'user:pass'))`

Edit: also, this may not apply because you say it works 30% of the time, but just be aware of common forms of encoding for Auth headers, eg, base64.