# Curl request is failing on the SSL?

Tags: php, curl, libcurl

I have this code

```
    if(ereg("^(https)",$url))
        curl_setopt($curl,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER,false);
    // execute, and log the result to curl_put.log
    $result = curl_exec($curl);


    $error = curl_error($curl);
```

The error specified is

```
SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104
```

Any ideas on the cause

Comment: is this not the same question? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3875674/my-password-curl-is-failing-sometimes

Comment: not even close...

Comment: Please note that [disabling VERIFYPEER or VERIFYHOST makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With SSL, make sure that you have [openssl extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.openssl.php) turned on from php.ini.

Comment: How do I turn that on?

Comment: in the PHP.ini file if you are using WAMPP or XAMPP , but still, after enabling it, i am having the same error code

Answer (score 32):

I encountered a similar cryptic error while working with a third-party library. I tried the `CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFY[PEER|HOST]` but it made no difference. My error message was similar:

```
SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 54
```

So I visited http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html, looking for the error code 54.

```
CURLE_SSL_ENGINE_SETFAILED (54) Failed setting the selected SSL crypto engine as default!
```

This was wrong though - I was making other HTTPS requests using curl in other parts of the application. So I kept digging and found this question, [R & RCurl: Error 54 in libcurl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9346223/r-rcurl-error-54-in-libcurl), which had this gem:

> The output you see is from lib/ssluse.c in libcurl's source code and the "errno" mentioned there is not the libcurl error code but the actual errno variable at that time.

So, don't let the output of [curl_error()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) mislead you. Instead, use [curl_errno()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-errno.php) to obtain the **correct** error code, which in this case was actually 56, CURLE_RECV_ERROR. Had the wrong host name...

Comment: I got errno 104, instead it was also really 56, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I've had the same problem. It turned out, that the ssl on the target system had a bad configuration.

After checking the php curl module, the GuzzleHttp version, the openssl version I called the link in the browser and it worked. But with `curl --tlsv1 -kv https://www.example.com` on the console there was still an error.

So I checked the ssl configuration at https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/ It was rated with B. And there where some Online Certificate Status Protocol (OCSP) errors I haven't seen before. Finally I changed my configuration on the target system to the suggestions at https://cipherli.st/ restarted the webserver and everything worked. The new rating at ssllabs is now A+.

My nginx configuration (Ubuntu 14.04, nginx 1.4.6-1ubuntu3.5):

```
ssl     on;
ssl_certificate /etc/ssl/certs/1_www.example.com_bundle.crt;
ssl_certificate_key     /etc/ssl/private/www.example.com.key;

ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
ssl_ciphers "EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH";
ssl_ecdh_curve secp384r1; # Requires nginx >= 1.1.0
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
#ssl_session_tickets off; # Requires nginx >= 1.5.9
ssl_stapling on; # Requires nginx >= 1.3.7
ssl_stapling_verify off; # Requires nginx => 1.3.7
ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/private/dhparams.pem;
ssl_trusted_certificate /etc/ssl/startssl.ca.pem;
resolver 8.8.8.8 valid=300s;
resolver_timeout 5s;
add_header Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; www.example.com; preload";
add_header X-Frame-Options DENY;
add_header X-Content-Type-Options nosniff;
```

Comment: In my case I also needed to limit the `ssl_protocols` to `TLSv1.2` as v1 and v1.1 conflicted with the rest of my environment.

Answer (score 0):

I think you mean to use CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, not CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER

Answer (score 0):

add this:

> curl_setopt( $curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);

I had the same error and worked fine for me.

Comment: why use HTTPS at all if verify is off?

Comment: if you trust the channel, you can disregard the flag verify host, the encryption works, but you dont need to check the cert

Comment: This just makes the connection vulnerable to MITM attacks (see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13742121/372643)).

Comment: no if you are using this curl to get data from your own network, read unencrypted data do not implies attack, sometimes you dont need to encrypt this data.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error printed by the function `curl_error` but this is not necessarily related to SSL. It is better to print the precise error number with the function `curl_errno` and you can diagnose better from there. In my case it returned me a 52 error code and I could debug from there, in fact the other server was not sending any data.

Answer (score 0):

It means the destination server require an SSL communication.

You should generate an SSL certificate for your sending server from wich you run the CURL request

**Let's Encrypt is the first free and open CA**

Everything is described here [sslforfree.com](https://www.sslforfree.com/)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved this curl error: "SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104" by removing extra space from my url query parameter value (comma separated values).

For example:

https://example.com?a=123,456,SPACE_ADDED_BY_MISTAKE789

to

https://example.com?a=123,456,789