# If I get “Unknown SSL protocol error” via CURL, did the request go through?

Tags: php, ssl, curl

I was wondering if that error means my request went through and I'm failing to get a response, or it failed before transporting the info and then gave me back an empty response.

This is in relation to my prior question: [Why would I randomly receive "Unknown SSL protocol error" from CURL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10985233/why-would-i-randomly-receive-unknown-ssl-protocol-error-from-curl)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it surely failed to transport the info...
you can try this...

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
```

and make sure the SSL is working on your website/WAMP...

Comment: Your rep went from 34 to 49 just now ;)

Answer (score 0):

If you can't even agree on an SSL protocol with the peer you're certainly not going to transfer any data.