# PHP curl post request error 104

Tags: php, ssl, curl

Submitting POST request:

```
$data = array('InputSegments'=>$input_segment, 'cmdSubmit'=>'Submit');
$ch = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($data));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PORT, "443");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array(
                                        'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded'
                                        ));
$response = curl_exec($ch);
$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
$err_no = curl_errno($ch);
$err = curl_error($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $err_no.' '.$err;
```

**ERROR**

> 56 SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104cURL Error #:SSL read: error:00000000:lib(0):func(0):reason(0), errno 104

**php.ini**

OpenSSL support enabled

OpenSSL Library Version OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3876563/curl-request-is-failing-on-the-ssl ?

Comment: I checked that. open ssl is already enabled. Please check the edit.

Comment: 104 is returned from Curl when the connection was forcibly reset by the remote host. If OpenSSL is installed, then it might be that you've got a cipher mismatch.

Comment: @iainn: What does it mean? something needs to be fixed from third party server side or client side?

Comment: Does the full certificate chain work on the remote side? Or is there maybe something missing. I stumbled across old CA Certificates via cURL at several times. Browsers ignored it, but cURL threw an error.